# Regularity of quotient of polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I am trying to solve Exercise IV.2.3 from Liu's book. I want to prove that $K[x,y]/(x^2+y^3+t^n)$ is regular, where $K$ is the fraction field of a discrete valuation ring and $t$ is a uniformizing parameter.

I would like to apply the Jacobian criterion, but I do not know if $K$ is perfect.

Finding explicitly all maximal ideals and study the localizations seems too long, but maybe it is the way to go?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don’t need the field to be perfect to apply the Jacobian criterion (Theorem 4.2.19).

Comment: Thank you! I was using a different reference for commutative algebra and assumed that it was necessary.